# How to execute function? which type of parameter should?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how to use following function

```
public IList<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereCondition)
{
     return this.ObjectSet.Where(whereCondition).ToList<T>();
}
```

like

```
_tabmasterService.GetSingle( ... what should here.. );
```

Comment: come on guys this is not extension method how can someone answer this without knowing or at least assuming the type of _tabmasterService and whether the method is defined in that particular type or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_tabmasterService.GetAll(x => x.Name == "fred");
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example a call to GetAll would look something like this

```
_tabmasterService.GetAll(x => x.SomeProperty == someValue);
```

This is a bit of syntactic sugar around delegates. You can read a bit more [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx)