# How to execute function in MVC with Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how to use following function

Generic Function:

```
public T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereCondition)
       {
           return this.ObjectSet.Where(whereCondition).FirstOrDefault<>();
       }
```

Business logic wise:

//Now in the following function i would like to call Generic function.

```
public TabMasterViewModel GetSingle(Expression<Func<TabMasterViewModel, bool>> whereCondition)
       {

           _tabmasterRepository.GetSingle( .. what should be here.. );
       }
```

//Calling function from Controller level.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
       {
           return View(_tabmasterService.GetSingle(x => x.colID == id));
       }
```

I could not able to use the function, please suggest.

```
_tabmasterRepository.GetSingle( .. what should be here.. );
```

Thanks,
Imdadhusen

Comment: i want to return TabMasterViewModel type record

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute function? which type of paramter should?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235535/how-to-execute-function-which-type-of-paramter-should)

Comment: yes i have implemented code as suggested by you at the Controller level return View(_tabmasterService.GetSingle(x => x.colID == id));
but the i also have to pass the GetSingle to the Generic Function

Comment: maybe i have misunderstood then, i will delete my comment

Comment: the follow is like calling function from Controller >> Base >> Generic. and i have problem in Base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you modify your first generic function as

```
public T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereCondition)
{
     return context.CreateObjectSet<T>().Where(whereCondition).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

or create a genetic repository

```
public class RepositoryGeneric<TEntity>
{
    public RepositoryGeneric(Context context)
    {
        Context = context;         
    }

    protected ObjectContext Context { get; private set; }

    protected virtual ObjectSet<TEntity> ObjectSet
    {
        get { return Context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>(); }
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetByKey(params object[] keys)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(keys);
    }

    public TEntity GetSingle(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> whereCondition)
    {
        return ObjectSet.Where(whereCondition).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Edit:

using the generic function

```
TabMasterViewModel model = _tabmasterService.GetSingle(x => x.colID == id);
```

or using generic repository

```
var tabmasterRepository = new RepositoryGeneric<TabMasterViewModel>(new Context());
var model = tabmasterRepository.GetSingle(x => x.colID == id);
```

Comment: edited it to add an example. is entity type different from `TabMasterViewModel`?

Comment: No it same for TabMasterViewModel